# How to write Rules condition based on input data in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a Firebase Realtime Database which gets written to in a predicted structure.

Is there a way to verify using rules that the authenticated user's UID matches **one of the data input values?**

[I know it is possible to validate this using values from the tree structure](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth#leverage_user_information_in_rules), but in my case I want to compare the UID to data in the input JSON.

---

For example, in my case, the input data is in the following JSON data structure:

```
{ "UserID": "SOME_UID", "UserName": "SOME_USERNAME", "CompletionMoves": 3, "CompletionTime": 12.345 }
```

And it is posted to a location which includes a level name and then the user's UID, akin to `/Level3/SOME_UID`.

I want to verify the user's UID equals the value of UserID in the data.

I thought of trying the following rule logic, but it fails on tests for some reason on the uid comparison line:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "$level": {
      "$uid" : {
            ".read": "auth != null",
                    ".write": "auth != null 
                    && newData.child($level).child($uid).child('UserID').val() == auth.uid",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does anybody know what I am missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `newData` and `data` variables in security are snapshots of the (new) data at the node where the rule is declared. So you don't need to build the entire path to `UserID`, and can instead refer to it directly.

So instead of:

```
&& newData.child($level).child($uid).child('UserID').val() == auth.uid",
```

Use:

```
&& newData.child('UserID').val() == auth.uid",
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of '.child($uid)', try '.child(auth.uid)'.

This works for me (if I've understood your question correctly).